# Very basic Hyper-V Nic teaming recommendation needed

Tags: hyper-v, network-teaming

We are a small network of 25 only user. I have a Windows 2016 Standard File server that I plan on installing Hyper-V role. I've already created a separate v Disk (Raid 1) to contain vm's. One of the vm's will be a Server 2016 box that I plan on installing DC role. We are currently part of another parent company domain that we are divesting from. Presently, the 2 nics on the server are teamed. Can I leave them like that and still install the hyper-v role and use the team for my vm and my physical server concurrently or do (should I) I need to break up the team to allow 1 nic for the physical box and 1 for the vm?  Also, to eliminate a single point of failure, might I buy more nics and create 1 team for the physical box and 1 for the vm's? I welcome the Pros and Cons of options of any suggestions.

Comment: Hi. For such small site I would promote the fileserver to a domain controller. Why the need for HyperV ?

Comment: @yagmoth555 Maybe the server is underutilized and virtualization will let them do more things with it in future?

Comment: The server is definitely under-utilized, plus I want to take advantage of the 2 free windows server licenses that I get with the server purchase. The reason I don't want to promote the file-server is because I want to keep the dc role completely separate from the file serve role.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I agree, but like the OP state for the 1:2 right it got restriction, it's kinda why I asked (as it would finish in a fileserver role migration too.)

Answer (score 1):

I would dedicate one NIC for the VM and one for the host. I edited my advice as your switch does not support link aggregation.

As you want to use the 2 free instances of Windows Server inside a hypervisor, please know you would not be ok with the licensing as your host got a fileserver role. Technically speaking the OS will not block you, so you can do it.

Per the official Microsoft documentation;

> Windows Server Standard edition provides rights to use instances of
>   the software in two OSEs or two Hyper-V containers and unlimited
>   Windows Server containers when all cores on the server are licensed
>   (subject to a minimum of 8 core licenses per physical processor and a
>   minimum of 16 core licenses per server). As mentioned above, Standard
>   edition provides the right to use Windows Server as the Host OS (in
>   addition to two guest OS’s), **if it is used solely to host and manage
>   virtualized workloads**.

I would suggest to create the DC in a VM but to migrate the file server role to another VM, to leave the Hyper-V's role alone on the host if you don’t want to add license later on.

Comment: I don't understand the comment about, "please know for the hypervisor no role other than HyperV can be on it for having the 1:2 right". The physical is, and will remain the main file server for the company. all I'm trying to accomplish is to be able to use what i have to create a dc on this box as it is a very robust system. Why can't I just install the hyperv role on this physical server and install a windows 2016 server in the hyperv container? In other words, is there a restriction preventing me from having a file server role and a hyperv role on the same physical box?

Comment: The teaming is done via the windows server...No LACP as my switches are unmanaged.

Comment: @Rokrobster I edited my answer, and I tried to better phrase my advice

Comment: Thanks yamoth555! I didn't know about the licensing restriction. In fact, I discussed my plans with Dell prosupport and they didn't mention it. What are your thoughts about adding more nics to the host and creating 2 teams; one for host, the other for vm's???

Comment: @Rokrobster Adding NIC would be a good idea. I would create a TEAM for the host, but for the VM I would make a failover TEAM, as the switch is not layer2/3. A load balance team would work, but you could have strange network behavior from time to time.

Comment: A example, one of my customer used to have a load balance team without the switch config and the VMs seemed to work correctly, but intermitantly user from the VPN wasnt able to access server ressource, and such strange behavior. Killing the team fixed all thoses bugs

Comment: Thank you yamoth555. Every answer that you give me raises new questions from me. I'm unfamiliar with the term 'failover Team' that you mentioned. On the host my only option (I think?) is to create a Team; no particular type is offered. And since my switch is dumb (unmanaged), it provides nic failover. I haven't installed HyperV yet. Does HyperV offer options for teams, with one being, a 'failover Team'?  I really wish I had switches that had the capability of link aggregation (LACP).

Comment: @Rokrobster please see https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/nic-teaming/create-a-new-nic-team-on-a-host-computer-or-vm but as I read I seen in 2016 there is a team for switch independent's mode. It could fit your case then without a LACP. You can see the failover mode inside the document, but I think the switch independent's mode is your best answer.

Comment: @yamoth555 It turns out that my current 2 nic team is already setup as an Independent team. I plan on getting another 2 nic card to create another Independent team that I plan on using for my vms. Thanks again for all you help!

Comment: Please do not start adding hardware and certainly do not start creating more teams for this build unless you have performance charts that explicitly show high utilization. If you've got two NICs in a switch independent team right now, I would be surprised if you're above 5% utilization in the 90th percentile. More hardware/teams add complexity without a corresponding return. If you add a second physical switch and understand how to configure it without creating a loop, you can swing one cable from one NIC to it and have no single point of failure and sufficient bandwidth.